# Export/Get Auto Response Rules

Tags: rest, case-auto-response

Is it possible to export auto response rules in some way? Ultimately I want to either export them into Excel or display on a Visualforce page.

I've tried looking at the REST explorer on workbench but can't seem to find a way to GET anything to do with the rules. I know they aren't available in Eclipse.

Edit:
This what I have tried in the restExplorer:

> /services/data/v34.0/sobjects/AutoResponseRules/describe
>
> /services/data/v34.0/sobjects/AutoResponseRule/describe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to do this by using the excellent apex-mdapi project:
https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/tree/master/apex-mdapi/src

Unfortunately too much code to post and improve the quality of answer and I don't think I would be able to do the project justice :)